# C# Web browser window from application using stack

Tags: c#

Using stack how to do forward and backward browser page and I had a file which contains URL([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) it should be linkable to redirect the browser page  in C# winforms application without using browser class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am storing browser history in historyfile after the file it should be linkable so that it redirect the browser page from historylist.